# Typescript generics and intellisense

Tags: generics, knockout.js, intellisense, typescript

Using Typescript 0.9.1 and Knockout with my own class, if I write the following in a .ts file:

```
class Asset{
    AssetID: KnockoutObservable<number> = ko.observable();
}
```

and create a var:

```
var asset: KnockoutObservable<Asset> = ko.observable(new Asset()),
```

I would like to access the AssetId using:

```
asset.AssetId(123)
```

However intellisense only offers the ko.observable hints and TypeScript throws an error. Is this method of accessing typed objects supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you made asset an observable I believe you need to do `asset()`. So the complete syntax would be :

```
asset().AssetId(123)
```